# Diagnosing dropped samples from a usb microphone

Tags: debian, usb, audio

My usb microphone appears to be dropping samples, producing very glitchy recordings which are about 5% shorter than they should be. Here's an example recording of a periodic wave:

[image: 440 Hz test tone]

You can clearly see pieces of the wave missing. This happens using both arecord and SoX's "rec" command, at all bit depths and sampling rates.

[Edit:] The glitches are irregularly spaced from between 5-100 ms apart, and happen at all amplitudes, bit depths, and sampling rates. I have the latest firmware, updated today.

Any ideas about where to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Are you running the latest firmware? Older firmwares produced glitchy, unusable data from USB DACs I tried them with.

Comment: I updated again just now to verify - no change.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at this question the other day but your image was missing. Looking at it now, it's clear your waveform is being "snipped" in places.

I've had similar problems - audio loss during mic recordings - when the gain was set too high in `alsamixer`; check your levels. Clipping could be the culprit of this problem.

Comment: The glitch is constant, and happens at all amplitudes. The wave in the image above is at about -24db.

Comment: If your capture device supports DB boost, set it to zero. Failing that, look for some better drivers (preferably from the manufacturers website).

Comment: DB boost is already at 0 in alsamixer. The manufacturer doesn't offer drivers - it's a Samson Go USB mic, advertised as "plug-and-play." I'll try looking for other drivers elsewhere.

Comment: That's a condenser mic, which will probably require a bit more power. Are you using a USB hub? If not, I would advise doing so as the Pi power supply won't be enough

Comment: I'm not using a hub - I'll try to round one up, and try again.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Not yet. But I'm leaving this open in case I figure it out later.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a look at the waveform in the picture and it looks like it coould be missing samples possibly due to the processor having to perform other tasks (multi-tasking) and taking time-out to service an interrupt or another process.

You could try temporarily shutting-down other services while making recordings and see if that helps. My first target would be any internet conectivity as this might be connecting peridically as a background task and interrupting your recording software.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has a similar issue.

I have measured the exact same behaviour with my Samson GoMic USB microphone.
The issue could be completely resolved, by using a modified kernel.
There is a comfortable way to do this:

```
sudo BRANCH=fiq_split rpi-update
```

[You can find out more about it here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=39175)